# CursorLine colors

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, cursor

I configured my CursorLine to be lightyellow.

[image: cursorline screenshot]

I have a couple of issues here:

- First, lightyellow is marked as an error when it is a valid color. How can I avoid this?
- Second, when the cursor line is over an error, the error background color disappears and it is really hard to read the text. Is there any way of preventing this behavior?

[image: screenshot cursor line error]

Comment: Maybe set both `ctermgb` and `ctermfg` to something other than `none` ? Example: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_line

Comment: If I add `ctermfg` all the text in the line will be coloured in the color specified. So, I will lose the syntax highlight in that line, and I don't want it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The default syntax script for vim doesn't have `lightyellow` listed for `vimHiCtermColor`. You could patch it and submit your change to the vim_dev mailing list.

   Or, better, ask them if that is intentional.
2. `Error` as a lower priority than `CursorLine` but you can force it with this simple hack:

   ```
   hi Error cterm=reverse ctermbg=white ctermfg=red
   ```

   Instead of white text on red background, you use red text on white background and reverse them with the `reverse` attribute:

   - it gives you white on red,
   - it increases the priority of `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the GUI:

```
hi Error gui=reverse guibg=White guifg=Red
```